# add label at fit block top left corner

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to move the label at the top left corner of the fit block, but now it seems at the center.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,align=center},
    node distance=0.5cm and 3cm    
    ]
    \node[box] (N1) {Source};
    \node[box,below=of N1] (N2) {Destination};

    \node[draw,dashed,inner sep=8pt,fit={(N1) (N2)}] (fit) {label}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wish to use the same fit node but don't want to add another node for label purpose!

Comment: Why do you not want another node? What's the *exact* wanted location for "label"? There is a `label` option, e.g. `label={above left:label}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to put text on the upper left corner in the inside without another explicit or implicit node:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\MoveFitHeight}[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\fit@inner@sep{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}%
  }%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\fit@text@height{%
    \tikz@text@height
  }%
  \kern-\fit@inner@sep\relax
  \raisebox{\fit@text@height}[0pt][0pt]{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,align=center},
    node distance=0.5cm and 3cm
    ]
    \node[box] (N1) {Source};
    \node[box,below=of N1] (N2) {Destination};

    \node[
      draw,
      dashed,
      inner sep=8pt,
      fit={(N1) (N2)},
      align=left,
    ] (fit) {\MoveFitHeight{label}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) says:

> The above means that, generally speaking, if the node contains text
>   like box in the above example, it will be centered inside the box. It
>   will be difficult to put the text elsewhere, in particular, changing
>   the anchor of the node will not have the desired ffect. Instead, what
>   you should do is to create a node with the `fit` option that does not
>   contain any text, give it a name, and then use normal nodes to add
>   text at the desired positions. Alternatively, consider using the
>   `label` or `pin` options.

Another node is IMHO the cleanest way:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,align=center},
    node distance=0.5cm and 3cm
    ]
    \node[box] (N1) {Source};
    \node[box,below=of N1] (N2) {Destination};

    \node[
      draw,
      dashed,
      inner sep=8pt,
      fit={(N1) (N2)},
    ] (fit) {};
    \node[above right, inner sep=0pt] at (fit.north west) {above right};
    \node[below right, inner sep=0pt] at (fit.north west) {below right};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result explicit nodes]

Fine tuning can be done via options `inner sep`, `xshift`, or `yshift`.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested, here is a quick way you can do it with MetaPost.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    input boxes
    beginfig(1);
      boxit.main(image(
        label(btex \framebox[2.5cm]{Source} etex, origin);
        label(btex \framebox[2.5cm]{Destination} etex, (0, -cm)))); 
      main.dx = main.dy = 12pt;
      drawunboxed(main); draw bpath(main) dashed evenly;
      label.lrt(btex label etex, main.nw);
    endfig; 
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The key point is to insert the Source and Destination boxes (I chose to typeset them with a mere `\framebox`) into a greater box fit with the help of the `boxes` package of MetaPost.

Once this is done, it is very easy to have access to the upper left corner of this box: it is simply `main.nw`, where `main` is the name I have given to it and `nw` meaning “north-west”.

I have inserted the MetaPost coding into a LuaLaTeX program since it is the most direct way to include MetaPost into a LaTeX document.

[image]

For those who don't want to use LuaLaTeX, here is a more general version using the `gmp` package. (But you have to activate the `shell-escape` feature of your distribution to typeset it.)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[latex, shellescape, everymp={input boxes}]{gmp}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mpost*}
      boxit.main(image(
        label(btex \framebox[2.5cm]{Source} etex, origin);
        label(btex \framebox[2.5cm]{Destination} etex, (0, -cm)))); 
      main.dx = main.dy = 12pt;
      drawunboxed(main); draw bpath(main) dashed evenly;
      label.lrt(btex label etex, main.nw);
  \end{mpost*}
\end{document}
```